# Does 'Bebojn facile timigas per la tondro' sound natural?

Tags: translation

The original sentence

> Babies are easily frightened by thunders.

And how does `timas` and `timigas` change the meaning of the sentence?

Many thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to adapt the question-title so that more people can make use of it? I mean, it may answer more than just the title, which is very specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sentence does not have a subject, whilst the main verb requires it, so it's not even grammatical. In the original sentence ‘babies’ is the subject with a passive construction, which can be translated as

> Beboj estas facile timigitaj de tondroj.

However, because of Esperanto's flexible word order in these simple sentences, we can easily make this an active construction with *tondroj* as the subject:

> Bebojn facile timigas tondroj.

---

The difference between *timi* and *timigi* is, that the subject of *timi* is the thing that is scared while the object is the thing that causes fear; with *timigi* it's the reverse: the subject is the thing causing fear while the object is the thing being scared.

Note however, that with *timigi* the thing that causes fear need not be the thing that is being feared; for instance, I can cause you to be scared with a scary story about ghosts, which means you would be scared of ghosts, not of me; then still *Mi timigis vin* (I scare you) while *Vi ne timas min, sed vi timas fantomojn* (you're not scared of me, but of ghosts).

---

EDIT: Because of the comment left by [marcus](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/users/24/marcus) I thought it would be good to also clarify the use of *de* in my suggested sentence as opposed to *per* in the one from the asker. Consider:

> Beboj estas facile timigitaj **per** tondroj.

This has the implication that someone may utilize thunders in order to scare babies, rather than babies just *passively* being scared by them. The actual agent of the passive participle *timigitaj* is completely left out. An active formulation of the above would be

> Mi facile timigas bebojn per tondroj.

“I easily scare babies using thunders.” On the other hand, *de* in the sentence

> Beboj estas facile timigitaj **de** tondroj.

has the meaning of the agent related to the passive participle *timigitaj*. That is, an active version of this sentence is precisely the one I gave above:

> Tondroj facile timigas bebojn.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the Esperanto sentence literally means: *"«missing subject» scares babies easily using the thunder"*. The suggestions given by @Joffysloffy are very good +1

Comment: Thank you! Also, due to your comment (seeing ‘using’ in the translation) I have added more clarification on the difference between _de_ and _per_ in the sentence I suggested.